# Remove the json values

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I Have add json values in select box working fine 
     adding codings:

```
  function addSizeToList(JSON) {
o = '<option value="'+JSON.Size_ID+'"  label="'+JSON.Size_Name+'">'+JSON.Size_Name+'</option>';
$("#Size_ID").prepend(o);

}
```

how to remove adding values in json

My code following:

```
 function removeSizeToList(JSON) {
o = '<option value="'+JSON.Size_ID+'" label="'+JSON.Size_Name+'">'+JSON.Size_Name+'</option>';
$("Size_ID"+ o).remove()
}
```

how to remove select box json values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 function removeSizeToList(JSON) {
    $("#Size_ID option[value='"+JSON.Size_ID+"']").remove();
}
```

Comment: This is already answered, and also we were said `.find()` performs way faster than joined selectors, specially in the case of finding Element properties `:)`

Comment: You are welcome @user2563077.Pls mark the answer as correct one

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the option with the given value from the select

```
function removeSizeToList(JSON) {
    $("#Size_ID").find('[value="' + JSON.Size_ID+ '"]').remove()
}
```